# vagrant ansible The following settings don't exist: inventory_file

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, vagrant, ansible

I've pulled down a git repo and ran vagrant up but I'm getting this error message

```
The following settings don't exist: inventory_file
```

I've installed virtual box and vagrant and ansible for osx mountain lion.

But I can't get anything to work.

also when I run `ansible all -m ping -vvvv` I get

```
<192.168.0.62> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: Grant
<192.168.0.62> EXEC ['ssh', '-tt', '-vvv', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/Grant/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'Port=22', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '192.168.0.62', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1379790346.17-244145524385544 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1379790346.17-244145524385544 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1379790346.17-244145524385544'"]
192.168.0.62 | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/Users/Grant/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-192.168.0.62-22-Grant" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.62 [192.168.0.62] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.62 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.62 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Any ideas on what is going on will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 11):

For the `inventory_file` issue try changing the `Vagrantfile` to use `inventory_path` instead. I think this subtle change occurred with Vagrant 1.3.x. If you don't want to modify the `Vagrantfile` try using Vagrant 1.2.x.

When running:

```
ansible all -m ping -vvvv
```

This will use your current user and will look in the default location for the Ansible hosts inventory (`/etc/ansible/hosts`).

In order to get it working with a Vagrant defined VM you need to use the `vagrant` user, specify the SSH key to use during the connection and specify the location of the hosts inventory, e.g.

```
ansible all \
  -i provisioning/inventory # <-- or wherever the inventory is \ 
  -m ping \
  -u vagrant \
  --private-key ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

Answer (score 3):

It has been repeated all over the block about using `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` but I found that it was using actually `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`, in the path where the `Vagrantfile` is. They probably changed their key generation to be per-machine, not user-wide, but the documentation does not reflect that yet.

So for the whole command, it would be:

`ansible-playbook -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory --private-key=.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -u vagrant playbook.yml`

You can check whether is one or the other by running `vagrant ssh-config` and looking for the `IdentityFile` value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the inventory_file, private_key and ssh_user every time, you can put those into an ansible config file. See my more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25316963/502457

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ansible all -i inventory -m ping -u vagrant --private-key ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/Users/dxiao/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
testserver | success >> {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}

$ cat inventory
testserver ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/Users/dxiao/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

it works.