# "vagrant provision" works, but I cannot send an ad-hoc command with Ansible

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I have set up a machine with Vagrant, and created a basic Ansible playbook for it. 
Everything works as expected when I run

```
vm-abla> vagrant provision
```

But I cannot send an ad-hoc command to the machine with Ansible, why is that?
I have highlighted the line which I think might indicate the cause.

```
vm-abla> ansible jon -i provisioning/hosts -a "echo 'TEST'" -vvvv

<192.168.33.2> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: user
<192.168.33.2> REMOTE_MODULE command echo 'TEST'
<192.168.33.2> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-vvv', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/user/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '192.168.33.2', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1394126994.26-73015876561126 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1394126994.26-73015876561126 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1394126994.26-73015876561126'"]

192.168.33.2 | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master

### debug1: Control socket "/home/user/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-192.168.33.2-22-user" does not exist

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.33.2 [192.168.33.2] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/user/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.33.2" from file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 32:53:5d:95:d9:2b:c0:92:ab:1d:a4:87:95:a6:5a:e2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.33.2" from file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.33.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fa1272d15d0)
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa (0x7fa1272d1610)
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x7fa1272cd270)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

After reading the Troubleshooting section of [this page](https://discern.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/vagrant-ansible-install.html), I have also tried to use Vagrant's SSH key by adding this at the end of the command, with a very similar result:

```
-c ssh --private-key=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

Any idea of what is going wrong?
Thank you

EDIT: Ah! I managed to login to the machine using SSH, but I had to declare that I was user "vagrant" on the virtual machine, like this:

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.33.2
```

So, now that this works, how could I do the same with ansible? (or would this not be a good solution?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @mascip already self-answered, you need to tell ansible: inventory_file, ssh_user and ssh_private_key. (I don't think the `-c ssh` setting is needed.)

The "elegant way" is to put all those settings into a project-specific ansible.cfg file. Then you can just run `ansible jon -a "echo 'TEST'"`.

One "gotcha" is that ansible.cfg must be in the same directory as where you're running the `ansible` command. I like to put ansible.cfg under my ansible directory, so that means I need to `cd` there first. If you want to run `ansible` from your project root, then put ansible.cfg there instead (and adjust the relative paths in the sample config file below).

ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]

remote_user = vagrant
private_key_file = ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key

# aka inventory file
hostfile = ../.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory
```

Comment: Since Vagrant v1.7.3, the private key file is stored in generated inventory file, and is unique per host, so don't hardcode it in your `ansible.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed:

```
vm-abla> ansible jon -i provisioning/hosts -a "echo 'TEST'" -vvvv -c ssh --user=vagrant --private-key=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

But if someone has a more elegant or secure solution, I'm interested.